# Change a PHP variable on the fly (while being executed)

Tags: php, command-line, on-the-fly

I have a for-ever-running PHP script currently started on my machine.

I made some changes in the source code of that script: I've changed the value of one variable in global scope.

Now, if I want these changes to be applied, I could stop and restart the script, but then I would loose all the computations this script has already made. So I want to apply the code changes I made without restarting the PHP interpreter instance.

Can I do that?

What I thought about is maybe plug XDebug in the existing "php.exe" process, and try to alter the variable from there, but I don't know how to.

Another idea would be to use a software that could alter the PHP interpreter memory or symbol table, but I don't know any tool like that.

I started this script without a debuger, but I know that Java, when started with a debuger, has some option to "apply code changes without restarting the Java instance". Is there something similar for PHP interpreter?

---

There is a sample you might try yourself. Create the PHP file 'myfile.php' with the following code:

```
<?php
if (ob_get_status()) {
    ob_end_clean();
}
$variable = 'Hello';
$i = mt_rand(0, 1000);
while (true) {
    $i++;
    echo $variable . ' ' . $i . PHP_EOL;
    sleep(1);
}
```

Run it in command line: `php -f myfile.php`

You are now in my current situation: the script is running for ever, and it contains a dynamic variable `$i` (that I can not actually know the current value in my real world case, because that real world case has no output).

The challenge is now **to change the value of `$variable` from 'Hello' to 'World'** (which represents the variable value I changed in my real world case), **but without loosing the current value of `$i`** (that represents the currently done computations).

Remember that you **cannot** alter the 'myfile.php' code before running the script for the 1st time: you **must** run the 'myfile.php' with the exact same code as I shown, and then start the challenge.

Comment: What stops you from changing it inside the while loop?

Comment: @ManuelMannhardt Because the PHP process has already started: if I change the PHP code, I need to stop and restart the PHP process for the new code to apply and in my real life example, I need to keep it running

Comment: Use an environment variable / file / db to store the data and retrieve it on each iteration of the loop? Though PHP is not meant to run indefinitely. There are bound to be better solutions, but we don't know what you're trying to do.

Comment: @JonStirling I edited and tried to make the needs more clear, but I cannot use an environment variable now (it would need to alter PHP code and restart the CLI): the issue is that PHP process is already running, and so altering code requires to restart it AFAIK. It's not a usual case to run a PHP indefinitly, indeed, but that can be a usage of this scripting language and interpreter :)

Comment: Environment variables won't work since they're read at script startup, but the general point about needing to store this value externally to the script is true. It could be in a database, a nosql store, a text file, a [shared memory segment](http://php.net/manual/en/shmop.examples-basic.php), or any number of other things. Knowing more about *why* you need to do this might help narrow it down - this feels a bit like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) right now.

Comment: @iainn My real world issue is that I have an indefinitly-running PHP script started, and I need to change one variable in it, but I cannot stop and restart it otherwise I will loose all the computation it has already done, so I need a way to change the variable value without stopping and restarting the script interpreter. I will try to see if I can plug XDebug on a running PHP instance and see if I can change variables from there maybe...

Answer (score 1):

Not within current file except invoking a function which tries to check a condition:

```
$variable = function() {
    return date('l') == 'Saturday' ? ':)' : ':(';
};
while (true) {
    echo $variable() . PHP_EOL;
    sleep(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, you need to read a new value from somewhere ! You can use a database or a temporary file like this :

file1.php

```
<?php

file_put_contents('var.tmp','hello');

while(true) {
    $var = file_get_contents('var.tmp');
    print $var . PHP_EOL;
    sleep(1);
}
```

file2.php

```
<?php

while(true){
    $var = readline('$var > ');
    file_put_content('var.tmp',$var);
}
```

Open 2 terminals, in the first one :

`php -f file1.php`

And the second one

`php -f file2.php`

Now you can write the value to the second terminal window and it's going to change in the first one.

Comment: Could work for next time, but my `file1.php` is already running, so I cannot make the changes in it without having to restart the currently running instance

Comment: you cannot change a variable inside the file that have already been started.